# Which is the best way to create an entity?

Tags: entities

I would like to use entity concept in my next project.So , is it good to use Entity Construction kit for creating entities ?
How about Model Entities ?
Which is better ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Entity Construction Kit](https://drupal.org/project/eck) (ECK) is a module to assist developers with creating their own entity types. If you want to export your entity types to code for version control and deployment use the [Features](https://drupal.org/project/eck) module. If you don't want to do this (i.e. take the long way) write your entity type code using [Model module](https://drupal.org/project/model) as an example to follow (essentially the same thing).

Comment: ECK is an easier / quicker option but coding from scratch will give you greater control and more flexibility...